# Razor pages - include additional parameter besides the model

Tags: razor-pages

Is possibility in Razor Pages to add additional paremeter besides the model?
I mean:

```
<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_SomePartial.cshtml" model="Model" @*add here another parameter somehow*@ />
```

Comment: Why don't you want to add the parameters to the model?

Comment: I'm doing this now, but I'm wondering if I can do something like this